# Injecting dependencies in ASP.NET MVC 5 Startup class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I am injecting dependencies in my controller as follows:

```
private IEmailSender _emailSender;

public HomeController(IEmailSender emailSender)
{
     _emailSender = emailSender;
}
```

Then resolving the dependencies using `Ninject` as follows:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind(typeof(IEmailSender)).To(typeof(EmailSender));   
}
```

So far everything is working fine. But I need to use this `IEmailSender` service in `Startup` class.

What I have tried so far is:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public Startup(IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

       _emailSender.SendEmail();
    }
}
```

But this does not work as application does not start because `Startup` class does not have parameter less constructor.

Any idea how I can use `IEmailSender` in Startup class?

Comment: Not ideal, but you might be able to do this using _Property Setter Injection_ - replace `private IEmailSender _emailSender;` with `[Inject]public IEmailSender _emailSender { private get; set; }` and remove the constructor

Comment: @StephenMuecke Does not work! `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Is `Startup()` begin called before call to initialize Ninject in `global.asax.cs`?

Comment: Another option might be `IEmailSender _emailSender = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IEmailSender>();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is creating the instance as expected bu the problem is that `async`method is not working as expected in the `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)`. Have you any thought regarding this please?

Comment: Not sure - problem is I cannot test/check it at the moment.

Comment: @StephenMuecke You can post this `IEmailSender _emailSender = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IEmailSender>();` as answer because this has solved the problem for whom I have posted the question. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181381/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tanvirarjel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ninject assigns itself as the current `DependencyResolver` instance, so you can use its `.GetService()` method to inject the concrete instance

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private IEmailSender _emailSender;
    public Startup()
    {
        _emailSender = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IEmailSender>();
    }
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
       _emailSender.SendEmail();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the kernel in `Program.cs` main function. So all the objects and services are registered before `Startup.cs` is called. This way *ninject* will able to resolve `IEmailSender` in startup class.

Comment: There is no `Program.cs` in a mvc web app

Comment: ok, my bad. then dont inject in ctor. use `kernel.Get<IEmailSender>()` to get an email sender instance.
`public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        var emailsender = kernel.Get<IEmailSender>();
        emailSender.SendEmail();
    }`